# Reliable delivery of iOS VOIP Push Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, push-notification, voip

Like many here, I was looking for a reliable way to deliver push notifications to an app for background processing.  I finally decided to use PushKit and all works well and the app was accepted into the AppStore, even though it's not a VoIP application.  I'm using the AWS SNS (Simple Notification Services) to handle the backend push processing.  However, even VoIP notification delivery will be throttled by iOS if you send excessive push notifications.  As a simple test, I can send several VoIP notifications over 2 - 3 min and they will deliver promptly and processed by the app in the background.  After I wait about 10 minutes (after locking the iPad and waiting for the application to be put to sleep by iOS) a subsequent VoIP push won't be delivered promptly by iOS.  AWS is pushing the notification, but iOS is not delivering it to the app.  I know this because as soon as I plug in the device, the notification is processed by the application.  As an aside, if the device is left plugged in, all notifications deliver and process promptly.

So my question is this: Have others noticed this behavior with VoIP pushes also?  Even though the iOS docs indicate that VoIP pushes are delivered immediately, it appears that iOS does throttle them if it considers the pushes "excessive" over some period of time.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I have exactly same issue. I don't know where to look or what should I change. I'm 100% sure application is not crashing. iOS throttling is extremely random. Sometimes device wake up after 8h, sometimes not after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, When you keep your app in background then you receives push notification. but when your app is in terminated then don't receive push notification.

Possibly your app gets crash when it is in killed ( terminated ) state.

Pushkit silent notification is always with higher priority and works well all the time.

Try below things to find out cause and solution.

(1) Debug your app in killed ( terminated ) state, like app is crashing or not

(2) Send silent notification with simple php code using pem and certificates ( Both case background and killed ( terminated ) )

(3) Check pushkit integration steps, if your app is not registered for VOIP, then it would not receive silent notification.

[image]

[image]

**Debug pushkit notification in terminated state**

- Put debug pointer on delegate methods
- Go to edit scheme
- Select run option then Launch -> Wait for executable to be launched
- Send push kit payload from back end
- Once you get payload on device
- it will automatically invoke and debug pointer will invoke at delegate methods.

[image]

[Refer some material](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Comment: Does it worked for you? if yes then you can accept answer.

Comment: PushKit silent notifications are NOT reliable and doesn't work that well. I have tested this on my VOIP app and also on Skype. There is no guarantee that they will be delivered in reasonable time (some of them had 1 minute delay!) when iPad is in some form hyper sleep.

Comment: So that way, there is no guarantee for whatsapp and skype call or video call, right ? But this works. in iOS either pushkit or callkit is only dependency to achive such scenario. If configured properly then this work perfectly, may be there is delay but it works well.